# Understanding dynamics on Lie Groups

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-derivative, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm trying to understand the definition of "Group Affine" systems (from Theorem 1 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10410)). I'll restate it here:

Let $\frac{d}{dt}X_t = f_{u_t}(X_t)$ be a vector field describing the system dynamics on a Lie Group $G$.

A system is group affine if the dynamics, $f_{u_t}(\cdot)$, satisfies:

$f_{u_t}(X_1X_2) = f_{u_t}(X_1)X_2 + X_1 f_{u_t}(X_2) - X_1 f_{u_t}(I_d)X_2$

for all $t>0$ and $X_1, X_2 \in G$.

First I want to make sure that I understand what each of these objects *are*, please correct me if I get anything wrong, because I'm not sure where my understanding is breaking down.

- $X \in G$ is a group element, that one's easy.
- $\frac{d}{dt}X \in T_XG$ is a vector in the tangent space of $G$ at the element $X$ representing the "flow" of $X$ through the group.
- $f(X) : G \to T_XG$ is a vector field on $G$ that maps each group element, $X$, to a vector in the tangent space $T_XG$.

If that's all correct, then I'm not sure how to interpret the operations $f_{u_t}(X_1)X_2$ and $X_1f_{u_t}(X_2)$. What are these binary operations? What does it mean to operate on $X_2$ (an element of $G$) with $f_{u_t}(X_1)$ which is an element of $T_{X_1}G$? What space does the result live in? From the lhs it seems like it should live in $T_{X_1X_2}G$.

Comment: It does say that $\mathcal G$ is a matrix group (so a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$, or maybe of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$?), so the Lie algebra of $\mathcal G$ is going to be a vector subspace of matrices.  So the operation is probably matrix multiplication.

Comment: For example, if $\mathcal G$ is the group of determinant one matrices, then the Lie algebra is the space of trace zero matrices.

Comment: Actually that does help quite a bit. Okay, so I have a follow up. Let's say $G$ is $SO(3)$ then the operation is matrix multiplication like you said. Would the analagous operation in the group of unit quaternions (also representing rotations) just be quaternion multiplication?

In the specific case of groups representing rotations, is there a good interpretation for what this operation means?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "analogous operation" or how the unit quaternions are related to $SO(3)$

Comment: They are both used to represent 3D rotations.

Answer (score 1):

This notation is specific to matrix Lie groups, but is easily extended to general Lie groups, as explained below.

Suppose first that $G$ is a matrix Lie group, so $G \subset M$ is a manifold inside a vector space $M$ of square matrices of a given size.

Now the following holds.

If $X \in G$, and $u \in T_XG$, in the sense that $u$ is a vector in $M$ tangent to $G$ at $X$ (in $M$), then, for any $Y\in G$:
$$ Y u \in T_{YX}G \qquad u Y \in T_{XY}G $$
where $Y u$ and $uY$ are matrix multiplications in $M$.

It looks specific to matrix Lie groups, but is in fact quite general. For a *general* Lie group now, pick $Y\in G$ and define the functions $L_Y \colon G \to G$ by $L_Y X := YX$, and $R_Y \colon G \to G$ by $R_Y Xh := XY$. Their tangent maps at $X\in G$ are so that $TL_Y \colon T_X G \to T_{YX}G$ and $TR_Y \colon T_X G \to T_{XY}G$.

Now, if $G$ is a matrix Lie group, and if $u \in T_X G$, then the tangent vector $Yu$ above is exactly $TL_Y u \in T_{YX}G$ (when embedded in $M$), and $uY$ is exactly $TR_Y u \in T_{XY}G$ (when embedded in $M$).